# NoClassDefFoundError exception in weblogic

Tags: tomcat, weblogic, noclassdeffounderror

I have developed a web application in Tomcat earlier and I had some jar files in my `tomcat/lib` directory. Now I am trying to run my application on weblogic server so I have installed weblogic 10.3.6, created a weblogic domain and deployed my application. I copied my jar files which I placed earlier in `tomcat/lib` to below lib directory:

```
Middleware/user_projects/domains/my_domain/lib/
```

I believe lib directory should be in class-path but when I access the class file in my web application I am getting below error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sample/TestManager
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:295)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.FilteringClassLoader.findClass(FilteringClassLoader.java:101)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.FilteringClassLoader.loadClass(FilteringClassLoader.java:86)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:295)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:295)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:43)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:171)
```

Comment: com/sample/TestManager is a class that is in one of the jars you copied in Middleware/user_projects/domains/my_domain/lib/ ?

Comment: Go to the server start tab for the server and manually add it to the classpath to see if that resolves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to ask for clarification but I am new and stackoverflow is not allowing me to ask for clarification. Hence I am posting as an answer

When you place something in DOMAIN_HOME/lib, remember the JARS in the will not be appended to the system/server classpath. The classloader that gets created is a child of the system/server classloader.

So, any classes that are in JARs in the DOMAIN_HOME/lib directory will only be visible to applications, such as WARs, EARs, etc.

Consider this:

- if your war/ear class is  package1.A
- if system/server classpath has a jar file that contains package2.B
- if DOMAIN_HOME/lib has a jar file that contains package3.C

And if you refer:

a) package2.B from package1.A

b) package3.C from package2.B

then "a" would pass but "b" would fail with similar error what you are getting.